# Terraform Module issue getting instance type argument is not expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am getting below error while apply the below tf file.

> Error: Unsupported argument
> instance_type = "t2.large"
> An argument named "instance_type" is not expected here.

I am calling the module as mentioned below

```
module "app-server" {
          source        = "../../modules/ec2"
          instance_type = "t2.large"
        }
```

---

```
variable "instance" {
            type = string
            default = "t2.micro"
        }
        
        variable "sg"{
            type = list
            default = [22,80,443,6801]
        }
        
        variable "ami" {
          type = map(any)
          default = {
            "us-east-1" = "ami-026ebd4cfe2c043b2"
            "us-west-2" = "ami-00aa0673b34e3c150"
            "ap-sout-1" = "ami-008b85aa3ff5c1b02"
          }
        }
        
        variable "region" {
            type = string
            default = "us-east-1"
        }
        
        
        locals {
          common_tags = {
            owner   = "devops_team"
            service = "backend"
          }
        }
        
        
        resource "aws_instance" "app01" {
            ami = lookup(var.ami,var.region)
            instance_type = var.instance
            availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
            vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.web-sg.id]
            key_name = "ec2-key"
            tags = local.common_tags
            connection {
              type =    "ssh"
              user = "ec2-user"
              private_key = file("./ec2-key.pem")
              host = self.public_ip
            }
            provisioner "remote-exec" {
                on_failure = continue
                inline = [
                    "sudo yum install -y httpd",
                    "sudo systemctl restart httpd",
                    "sudo systemctl enable httpd"
                ]
              
            }
        }
        
        
        resource "aws_security_group" "web-sg" {
             name        = "allow_tls"
             description = "list of ingressports"
              dynamic "ingress" {
                for_each = var.sg
                iterator = port
                content {
                    from_port   = port.value
                    to_port     = port.value
                    protocol    = "tcp"
                    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
                }
              }
              egress {
                description = "Outbound Allowed"
                from_port   = 0
                to_port     = 65535
                protocol    = "tcp"
                cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
        
            }
        }
        
        resource "aws_ebs_volume" "web-ebs" {
          availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
          size              = 40
        
          tags = {
            Name = "web-ebs-volume"
          }
        }
        
        resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs_att" {
            device_name = "/dev/sdh"
            volume_id = aws_ebs_volume.web-ebs.id
            instance_id = aws_instance.app01.id
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `instance`, not `instance_type`:

```
module "app-server" {
     source        = "../../modules/ec2"
     instance      = "t2.large"
}
```